# How to share the same ClientId in two different environments (sandbox and production)

Tags: identityserver4

I'm developing an API using IdentityServer4 for authentication. I have already configured the stores to use EF Core and I'm using Asp.Net Identity too.
To improve the experience of the users, we want them to try our API on sandbox after signing up and offering them an autogenerated ClientId and ClientSecret. Once they want to go to production, we want to generate another ClientSecret for the production environment.

In other words, we want to reuse the ASP.NET Identity user and the IdentityServer client except for the secret.

We have different urls, databases, etc. for sandbox and production. Currently we are using two different IdentityServer servers and databases, but we are considering to share the same IdentityServer server and database for both environments.

Is this scenario supported in any way?

EDIT 1:
As stated on a comment to the response of travis.js, environments should be called live and sandbox instead of production and sandbox, as both environments are production ready to my clients.

EDIT 2:
The app embedding IdentityServer and Asp.Net Identity is the app that will manage the sign up, so the live and sandbox API will ask this app for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You'll run into problems trying to reuse the same the IdentityServer app/db under different urls. The hostname of your IdentityServer instance part of what make it unique and authoritative. One instance can't have two different authority names to my knowledge.

Sounds like a basic data migration issue, i.e., you just need to some of the sandbox config data moved up the production database.

Whatever app handles the user registration and "go live" features can do that work. It would just need access to both databases.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't separate between production and sandbox but between live and sandbox, as both of them are production ready to my clients. Both sandbox and live should use the same data for the user (email and password) but different client credentials for each environment (live and sandbox).